# py2exe is not properly including project submodules

Tags: python, py2exe, distutils

I am using `py2exe` to package a wxPython GUI for distribution on Windows.  This is a simple version of my directory structure:

```
\project
    my_gui.py
    setup.py
        \submodule1
            __init__.py
            one.py
        \submodule2
            __init__.py
            two.py
```

My GUI imports submodule1 and submodule2, yet when I run my setup script they do not show up in the distribution, and the GUI quits with errors (`ImportError: No module named submodule.one`).

I'm thoroughly confused.  The documentation says that py2exe should automatically discover imported modules and add them to the frozen binary.  Since this doesn't seem to be happening, how can I explicitly force py2exe to include those submodules?

When I add submodule1 to the "includes" list in my setup.py file, the build breaks with this error: `Import Error: "No module named submodule"`.

Any suggestions?

Update:

It looks like the problem was that I was actually keeping my setup script in a subdirectory, so I was running `python scripts/setup.py`.  That seems to be what broke the imports.  Oops.

Comment: You shouldn't need to include it as part of setup.py, how do you include submodule1 in the main project? Typically this is just an import statement.

Comment: If you haven't, consider Pyinstaller as well. For instance, without the need for a setup.py file, the line `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed fileName.py` could be used. This helped me to skirt some of the module import issues with Py2exe